# jQuery function running on page load instead of on Click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function I've written that I want to only execute on the click on an element...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(".black-sectors li a.adr-src").on("click", updateAddressDisplay);

    updateAddressDisplay(null);
    function updateAddressDisplay(src) {
        # Function
    }

});
```

The above is running on the page load however?

Comment: Remove `updateAddressDisplay(null);`

Comment: Provide html too for better undeerstanding or else can you setup a jsfiddle

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2):

That'll be because you call it, right above where it's defined:

```
updateAddressDisplay(null); //Function called
function updateAddressDisplay(src) {
    # Function
}
```

Remove `updateAddressDisplay(null);` and it won't get called on page load.

Answer (score 0):

try removing `updateAddressDisplay(null);`

also you call pass some parameter with function on click call.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(".black-sectors li a.adr-src").on("click", updateAddressDisplay);

  //    updateAddressDisplay(null);
    function updateAddressDisplay(src) {
        # Function
    }

});
```